# missing 1 required positional argument: 'first'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the selected listbox value but TypeError keeps appearing. I tried including 'first' into the brackets but it doesn't work. Does anyone know what is this error about?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd

def saver():
     x = df1[df['MFG Device'].str.contains(values)]

def CurSelet(evt):
    global sel
    temp=list()
    for i in lbox.curselection():
        temp.append(lbox.get(i))

    allitems=list()
    #for i in range(lbox.size()):
        #allitems.append(lbox.get(i))

    for i in sel:
        if i in allitems:
            if i not in temp:
                sel.remove(i)

    for x in lbox.curselection():
        if lbox.get(x) not in sel:
            sel.append(lbox.get(x))

lbox = Listbox(window, width=30, selectmode=SINGLE)
lbox.place(x=15,y=150)
lbox.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', CurSelet)

values = lbox.get()
```

Shell:

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
Traceback (most recent call last):
    values = lbox.get()
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'first'
```

Update:

I tried using lbox.get(index) and the program will stop responding.

Comment: Can you share the `Listbox()` func code, this is missing code.

Comment: You need to provide index to `Listbox.get()` function, for example, `lbox.get(0)` to get the first item in the listbox.

Comment: @FishingCode edited just now.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. You must provide an index to the `get` method.

Comment: @FishingCode: `Listbox` in a class defined in the `tkinter` module — that's probably why there is no definition in the question.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for clearing that up. Now, it makes sense.

Comment: What is `index` mentioned in your *Update*? Better read the document on how to use [`Listbox.get()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm#Tkinter.Listbox.get-method).

Answer (score 1):

> I tried including 'first' into the brackets but it doesn't work

A positional argument is not a keyword argument (one that needs written out).

ListBox has a function `get ( first, last=None )`

> Returns a tuple containing the text of the lines with indices from first to last, inclusive. If the second argument is omitted, returns the text of the line closest to first.

You need to say `get(0)`, for example, or `get(0, last=len(some_data))` if you want all the data, where `some_data` is the list of data in that ListBox

---

Note: You did use it correctly (twice) at `lbox.get(x)`

---

Also: Your lone `lbox.get(<some_number>)` call will return None once you give an argument because `CurSelet` function has not yet been executed

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make sense. `lbox.get()` will not return `None`. It will throw the error that is reported in the question.

Comment: I meant once it was properly called

Comment: It still won't return `None`. It will return an empty string.